# How to get data from API - php - curl

Tags: php, api, curl

How can I get data ( image ) from api url?

Api result:

```
info = { "title" : "aaaaa", "image" : "bbbbb" };
```

Api url:

```
http://www.example.com/api
```

Code:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/api');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$obj = json_decode($result);
echo $result->image;
?>
```

```
Array
(
    [curlResult] => info = { "title" : "aaaaa", "image" : "bbbbb" };
    [info] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://127.0.0.1/api.txt
            [content_type] => text/plain
            [http_code] => 200
            [header_size] => 237
            [request_size] => 55
            [filetime] => -1
            [ssl_verify_result] => 0
            [redirect_count] => 0
            [total_time] => 0
            [namelookup_time] => 0
            [connect_time] => 0
            [pretransfer_time] => 0
            [size_upload] => 0
            [size_download] => 48
            [speed_download] => 48
            [speed_upload] => 0
            [download_content_length] => 48
            [upload_content_length] => 0
            [starttransfer_time] => 0
            [redirect_time] => 0
            [certinfo] => Array
                (
                )

            [primary_ip] => 127.0.0.1
            [primary_port] => 80
            [local_ip] => 127.0.0.1
            [local_port] => 61662
            [redirect_url] => 
        )

    [errno] => 0
    [error] => 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to try and debug this would be to check the curl info array, or curl error.

```
<?php
/**
 * Handles making a cURL request
 *
 * @param string $url         URL to call out to for information.
 * @param bool   $callDetails Optional condition to allow for extended       
 *   information return including error and getinfo details.
 *
 * @return array $returnGroup cURL response and optional details.
 */
function makeRequest($url, $callDetails = false)
{
  // Set handle
  $ch = curl_init($url);

  // Set options
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  // Execute curl handle add results to data return array.
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  $returnGroup = ['curlResult' => $result,];

  // If details of curl execution are asked for add them to return group.
  if ($callDetails) {
    $returnGroup['info'] = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $returnGroup['errno'] = curl_errno($ch);
    $returnGroup['error'] = curl_error($ch);
  }

  // Close cURL and return response.
  curl_close($ch);
  return $returnGroup;
}

$url = /* some url */
$response = makeRequest($url, true);

// Check your return to make sure you are making a successful connection.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
?>
```

Seeing if you are successfully making the connection, and then also exactly what you are getting back in the response should give you a better idea of how to handle parsing it.

**EDIT**

It looks like there is some non-JSON string data that is preventing the `json_decode` function from working. This is less than ideal, but it happens. Following method should help in this specific case, but is just a workaround to an issue involving bad data.

```
// continuing from above :) formatted for readability

/**
 * Separates JSON string from unnecessary data, parses into
 * an object and returns.
 *
 * @param string $curlResult String returned from cURL call.
 *
 * @return object $jsonObject Parsed JSON object. 
 */
function cleanJsonString($curlResult) {
  // Separates result string into array at " = ".
  $responseChunks = explode(" = ", $curlResult);

  // Removes semicolon from end of JSON string.
  $jsonString = substr($responseChunks[1], -1);

  // Parse JSON string into object.
  $jsonObject = json_decode($jsonString);

  return $jsonObject;
}

// Clean result.
$jsonObject = cleanJsonString($response['curlResult']);

// Print image object property.
echo $jsonObject->image;
```

Comment: just i want to print "bbbbb" or "aaaaa"

Comment: So that should print every single piece of information possible from your curl request. If your response (`$response['curlResult']`)  looks like the object you expect it to you should be able to `json_decode` it. if you can't then something is going wrong, thus all of the other info. Look through the return to see where your call is going awry.

Comment: @D Lowther . I am a beginner .. i used this code before .... `<?php
$url = 'http://127.0.0.1/api.txt';
$output = file_get_contents($url);
echo $output;
?>`  but i can't print "aaaaa", or  "bbbbb" :/

Comment: I think i see the issue. your request is returning `"info = {/*object*/}"` if you are pulling that from your local and trying to simulate JSON the file should just be `{/*object}` the `info = ` part is turning it into an invalid json string. I can add an example of stripping that info part out if you can't change the api.txt file to use a valid object.

Comment: ok sir .. @D Lowther . i can't change or delet `"info"` thank you ^^

Comment: Edit added to original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if the image is actual blob content or url link may change the way you display the image.

If content, you need to get the MIME type in order to display properly so you can set the proper page headers.

If link, visit that webpage.

Comment: :) Just a text (image url) = bbbbb

Comment: So what is the current issue? You are unable to get the image URL? Or you are trying to use the image URL?

Comment: @ Paul Makhnovskiy i can't get image url (bbbbb)

Comment: instead of echo $result->image; 
do:  echo $obj->image;

When you decode the $results, you add into $obj variable which holds all the json content.

Answer (score 0):

In your api:

1. Read entire image content to string. (file_get_contents)
2. Encode it to base64 string. (base64_encode)
3. Add it to returning result. (replace "image" = "bbbbb")

This looks:

```
$result = array(
    "title" => "aaaaa",
    "image" => "bbbbb"
);
$result["image"] = file_get_contents("path/to/your/image/file");
$result["image"] = base64_encode($result["image"]);
$result = json_encode($result);
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo $result;
```

And in your Code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.example.com/api');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$obj = json_decode($result);
// Do it if you encoded image string
$image_string = base64_decode($obj->image);
// Create image from base 64 decoded string
$image = imagecreatefromstring($image_string);
// And save your image as desired type (png or jpeg)
imagepng($image, "path/to/save/your/image/as/png");
```

EDIT: Do you can provide server side code. the code you have works as expected where is the problem?

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed explanation , excuse me :( but i want to  print this text "aaaaa" or this "bbbbb"

Answer (score 0):

Use `DOMDocument` to get image url

```
   $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.halalfoodrecipe.com/recipe/index');
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $obj = json_decode($result);

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($result);

    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $img) {
        echo $img->getAttribute('src');
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed explanation , excuse me :( but i want to print this text "aaaaa" or this "bbbbb"