# Scraping source code <script> tag from a web page

Tags: php, screen-scraping

I'm looking for a way to scrape some source code. The information I need is inside a  tag similar to this.

```
<script>
.......
var playerIdMap = {};
playerIdMap['4'] = '614';
playerIdMap['5'] = '84';
playerIdMap['6'] = '65';
playerIdMap['7'] = '701';
getPlayerIdMap = function() { return playerIdMap; };   // global
}
enclosePlayerMap();
</script>
```

I am trying to grab the contents of the playerIdMap numbers eg: 4 and 614, or the whole line for that matter..

Comment: Have you tried reading the HTML file, checking if each line has "playerIdMap" in it and then saving the ones that do? What about a Regular Expression to grab the playerIdMap array keys and value? You can even explode playerIdMap (although that would be ineffective). There are many ways.

Comment: None of this is visible on the front-end to me. I have scraped images etc before, but have never tried anything that is part of the page source and not visible. How would I go about an expression? Thank you

Comment: Try this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584826/scrape-web-page-contents?rq=1
It describes many ways in which you can accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit-2**

Complete PHP code inspired from code at [How to get data from API - php - curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42431286/how-to-get-data-from-api-php-curl)

```
<?php
/**
 * Handles making a cURL request
 *
 * @param string $url         URL to call out to for information.
 * @param bool   $callDetails Optional condition to allow for extended
 *   information return including error and getinfo details.
 *
 * @return array $returnGroup cURL response and optional details.
 */
function makeRequest($url, $callDetails = false)
{
  // Set handle
  $ch = curl_init($url);

  // Set options
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  // Execute curl handle add results to data return array.
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  $returnGroup = ['curlResult' => $result,];

  // If details of curl execution are asked for add them to return group.
  if ($callDetails) {
    $returnGroup['info'] = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $returnGroup['errno'] = curl_errno($ch);
    $returnGroup['error'] = curl_error($ch);
  }

  // Close cURL and return response.
  curl_close($ch);
  return $returnGroup;
}

$url = "http://www.bullshooterlive.com/my-stats/999/";
$response = makeRequest($url, true);

$re = '/playerIdMap\[\'(?P<id>\d+)\']\s+=\s+\'(?P<value>\d+)\'/';

preg_match_all($re, $response['curlResult'], $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);

//var_dump($response);
```

**Edit-1**

Sorry didn't realize you asked PHP question. Don't know why I assumed scrapy here. Anyways below php code should help

```
$re = '/playerIdMap\[\'(?P<id>\d+)\']\s+=\s+\'(?P<value>\d+)\'/';
$str = '<script>
.......
var playerIdMap = {};
playerIdMap[\'4\'] = \'614\';
playerIdMap[\'5\'] = \'84\';
playerIdMap[\'6\'] = \'65\';
playerIdMap[\'7\'] = \'701\';
getPlayerIdMap = function() { return playerIdMap; };   // global
}
enclosePlayerMap();
</script>';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

**Previous answer**

You can use something like below

```
>>> data = """
... <script>
... .......
... var playerIdMap = {};
... playerIdMap['4'] = '614';
... playerIdMap['5'] = '84';
... playerIdMap['6'] = '65';
... playerIdMap['7'] = '701';
... getPlayerIdMap = function() { return playerIdMap; };   // global
... }
... enclosePlayerMap();
... </script>
... """
>>> import re
>>>
>>> regex = r"playerIdMap\['(?P<id>\d+)']\s+=\s+'(?P<value>\d+)'"
>>> re.findall(regex, data)
[('4', '614'), ('5', '84'), ('6', '65'), ('7', '701')]
```

You need to get to the script tag using below

```
data = response.xpath("//script[contains(text(),'getPlayerIdMap')]").extract_first() 

import re
regex = r"playerIdMap\['(?P<id>\d+)']\s+=\s+'(?P<value>\d+)'"
print(re.findall(regex, data))
[('4', '614'), ('5', '84'), ('6', '65'), ('7', '701')]
```

Comment: ahh dang, sorry haven't used it in a long time..Wouldn't even know how to implement that into my php code if possible.

Comment: @KJThaDon, please check the updated answer. My bad, I was somehow under the impression that this is a scrapy question, which is why i posted python code

Comment: Thank you, I am a little lost though on some parts of it. It seems to do what I would like from looking at it, it will create an array?

I've tried adding my url to grab the code, but getting an error preg_match_all() expects at most 5 parameters, 6 given

Here's the code: https://paste.ee/p/MCjKN

Comment: Wow I think that is perfect, thank you so much! Very readable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154179/discussion-between-kjthadon-and-tarun-lalwani).